# Haskell newtype that flips semigroup operation?

Tags: haskell, monoids, semigroup

Is there any newtype in base that would basically achieve the following?

```
newtype SemigroupFlip a = SemigroupFlip a

instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (SemigroupFlip a) where
  (SemigroupFlip a) <> (SemigroupFlip b) = SemigroupFlip (b <> a)

instance Monoid a => Monoid (SemigroupFlip a) where
  mempty = SemigroupFlip mempty
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yep. That would be called [`Dual`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Dual).